# javascriptで配列の値をきれいに代入するには？？

Tags: javascript, html, html5

pythonで作ったリストデータをjavascriptのDate関数に送って処理させたいのですが、
d_train_timeには[2018, 9, 19, 8, 45]のようにデータが入っています。

```
var dt = new Date(d_train_time);
var dt = new Date(2018, 9, 19, 8, 45);//本当はこうしないといけない。
```

なので以下の様にに配列から一個ずつ取り出して代入する方法を考えているのですが、他に良いやり方はないでしょうか？

```
var dt = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript6 のスプレッド演算子をサポートしているような JavaScript 処理系であれば、以下のようにして配列を展開して引数に渡すことが可能です。

```
var d_train_time = [2018, 9, 19, 8, 45];
var dt = new Date(...d_train_time);
```

参考サイト

- [ECMAScript6 compatible table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)
- [Runtime Semantics: ArgumentListEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-argument-lists-runtime-semantics-argumentlistevaluation)

Comment: ありがとうございます！上手く出来ました。

Comment: IE11 のように動かないブラウザもあるのでターゲットブラウザを意識して使用してください。

Answer (score 1):

もしBabelでトランスパイルするのであればいっそのこと`const`もつかって

```
const dateArgs = [2018, 9, 19, 8, 45];
const date = new Date(...dateArgs);
```

のように書くことのほうが多いですが，トランスパイル無しでIE11対応もしたいときはこのシンタックスは使えませんね。

```
var dateArgs = [2018, 9, 19, 8, 45];
var date = new (Date.bind.apply(Date, [null].concat(dateArgs)));
```